# When extending this class, one of its methods now requires an extra argument. Why?

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

When I want to do a forward pass with an initialized `model = nn.Sequential` object, I simply use:

```
out = model(X)
# OR
out = model.forward(X)
```

However, I have tried extending the `Sequential` class, and now both of these methods suddenly require a second argument. For example, note in the following method my call to `self(x)`:

```
def train(self, trainloader, epochs):
        for e in range(epochs):
            for x, y in trainloader:
                x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss = self.criterion(self(x), y) # CALL OCCURS HERE
                loss.backward()
                self.optimizer.step()
```

This code now gives me `TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target'`.

**My Question:** Since I have done nothing but extend the class, why is this?

Code for full class below:

```
class Network(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, layers):
        super().__init__(self.init_modules(layers))
        self.criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.003)

    def init_modules(self, layers):

        n_layers = len(layers)
        modules = OrderedDict()

        # Layer definitions for input and inner layers:
        for i in range(n_layers - 2):
            modules[f'fc{i}']   = nn.Linear(layers[i], layers[i+1])
            modules[f'relu{i}'] = nn.ReLU()

        # Definition for output layer:
        modules['fc_out'] = nn.Linear(layers[-2], layers[-1])
        modules['smax_out'] = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

        return modules


    def train(self, trainloader, epochs):
        for e in range(epochs):
            for x, y in trainloader:
                x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss = self.criterion(self(x), y)
                loss.backward()
                self.optimizer.step()
```

Full stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-490e0b9eef22> in <module>
----> 1 model2.train(trainloader, 5, plot_loss=True)

<ipython-input-61-e173e5672f18> in train(self, trainloader, epochs, plot_loss)
     32                 x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
     33                 self.optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 34                 loss = self.criterion(self(x), y)
     35                 loss.backward()
     36                 self.optimizer.step()

c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py in forward(self, input)
     98     def forward(self, input):
     99         for module in self:
--> 100             input = module(input)
    101         return input
    102 

c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target'
```

Comment: Show the complete error message, including full stack trace.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Done.

Comment: Thanks to @Berriel for answering the question despite the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Since I have done nothing but extend the class, why is this?

Actually, you have. You chose the "wrong" base class. The `forward` of the `nn.Sequential` simply [goes through all modules](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/a2ef54c598261ad9fd15e1e85c71f15055652572/torch/nn/modules/container.py#L115-L118), and when you defined:

```py
self.criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
```

you registered the loss as a module. Therefore, when you call `self(x)`, you're actually calling `self.criterion(x)` at some point, hence the `TypeError`.

Comment: Dang! So anything that gets declared inside my subclass automatically gets added as a module to the parent class? That means that I can't do anything inside of `__init__`...

Comment: Yup, everything that derives from `nn.Module` :) Perhaps you'll have to change the base class.

Comment: This might deserve a follow on question, but how does one effectively use the child classes' `__init__`, if anything declared gets added as a module? I thought the point of calling `super().__init__()` was to be able to describe distinct characteristics of the child separate from the parent.

Comment: @rocksNwaves the problem here is only because you used `nn.Sequential` as base class, which has as default `forward` method a pass through all registered modules. Usually, the forward method is implemented in the child class and you would not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `self.criterion` is an instance of the class `nn.NLLLoss`. You need to pass a torch tensor as a second argument, make sure `y` satisfies that type requirement. Also, I am not sure about this line `loss = self.criterion(self(x), y)` why call `self(x)`? The first argument is supposed to be the input data passed through an activation function.

Comment: If you look closely, you will see that criterion has two arguments passed to it. One is `self(x)` which is the feedforward result (as you say, passed through an activation function which is defined in the class `__init__` statement). The second argument is `y`, which is the associated ground truth. For any given model, you can call `model(x)` or `model.forward(x)`. The former is recommended in PyTorch docs, and is why I chose to use `self(x)` rather than `self.forward(x)`. Both throw the same error anyway.